# RInside on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have R 3.0.3 installed with mac ports on OS X 10.9.2. I installed RInside with sudo R CMD INSTALL ~/Downloads/RInside_0.2.11.tgz (similarly Rcpp_0.11.1.tar). I am trying to compile a simple RInside Help World code from http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html. I am trying to use

```
g++ main.cpp -I/Users/robogos/Library/R/3.0/library/RInside/include/ -I/Users/robogos/Library/R/3.0/library/Rcpp/include/ -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/include/
```

and I get a long list of errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_REprintf", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::xsputn(char const*, long) in main-4b77b4.o
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::overflow(int) in main-4b77b4.o
  "_R_BindingIsLocked", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Environment_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>::bindingIsLocked(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const in main-4b77b4.o
  "_R_FlushConsole", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::sync() in main-4b77b4.o
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<true>::sync() in main-4b77b4.o
  "_R_NilValue", referenced from:
      Rcpp::wrap(char const*) in main-4b77b4.o
  "_R_UnboundValue", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Environment_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>::exists(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const in main-4b77b4.o
  "_Rf_defineVar", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Environment_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>::assign(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, SEXPREC*) const in main-4b77b4.o
  "_Rf_findVarInFrame", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Environment_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>::exists(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const in main-4b77b4.o
  "_Rf_install", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Environment_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>::assign(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, SEXPREC*) const in main-4b77b4.o
      Rcpp::Environment_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>::exists(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const in main-4b77b4.o
      Rcpp::Environment_Impl<Rcpp::PreserveStorage>::bindingIsLocked(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const in main-4b77b4.o
  "_Rf_mkString", referenced from:
      Rcpp::wrap(char const*) in main-4b77b4.o
  "_Rprintf", referenced from:
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<true>::xsputn(char const*, long) in main-4b77b4.o
      Rcpp::Rstreambuf<true>::overflow(int) in main-4b77b4.o
  "RInside::parseEvalQ(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main-4b77b4.o
  "RInside::RInside(int, char const* const*, bool, bool, bool)", referenced from:
      _main in main-4b77b4.o
  "RInside::~RInside()", referenced from:
      _main in main-4b77b4.o
  "RInside::operator[](std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in main-4b77b4.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried what Dirk Eddelbuettel suggested, but now I receive:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/stats/libs/stats.so, 6): Symbol not found: __gfortran_pow_r8_i4
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
  Expected in: /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/sys/os/maci64//libgfortran.2.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/stats/libs/stats.so, 6): Symbol not found: __gfortran_pow_r8_i4
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
  Expected in: /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/sys/os/maci64//libgfortran.2.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/stats/libs/stats.so, 6): Symbol not found: __gfortran_pow_r8_i4
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
  Expected in: /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/sys/os/maci64//libgfortran.2.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/stats/libs/stats.so, 6): Symbol not found: __gfortran_pow_r8_i4
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
  Expected in: /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/sys/os/maci64//libgfortran.2.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
make: Nothing to be done for `rinside_sample0.cpp'.
```

I have seen suggestions like `!unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH;`, but I do not know how to do this in my case.

Comment: Did you build RInside from source? If not, try that.

Comment: I have downloaded from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RInside/index.html and installed using `R CMD INSTALL ~/Downloads/RInside_0.2.11.tgz`. However, R was installed using Macports.

Comment: Install _from source_ via 'R CMD INSTALL RInside_0.2.11.tar.gz`. Note the `tar.gz` not `.tgz`.

Comment: I reinstalled using the tar.gz version, but the error output remains the same.

Comment: Why is your R trying to link to a `libgfortran` packaged with `MATLAB_R2013a`? Honestly, the trouble of using Homebrew R isn't worth it at this point. Just install the CRAN binary, or build R yourself from source (it's not that difficult).

Answer (score 0):

The use pattern is to

- cd into the `examples/standard/` directory
- run `make`
- or run `make rinside_sample0`  (or any other name) if you want to build just one.

You can add your own files, and `make nameofthefile` will build an executable.

In short, you can't just call `g++` as you did.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried, and it seems that there is a different problem too:

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Doing this gives the error: `fatal error: 'RInside.h' file not found` Do you know how to work around this?

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel After manually putting all the required header files into the appropriate location to run everything, I get the following error on my OSX 10.9 Mavericks: `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64` followed by `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` and `make: *** [rinside_sample0] Error 1`