# ld and clang error in RInside for Mac OSX

Tags: macos, clang, rinside

I want to try out RInside for Mac OSX.  I downloaded RInside from source using Terminal and then went into the `/inst/examples/standard` and tried to run `make`, as indicated in the answer to this thread: [RInside on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841842/rinside-on-mac-os-x)

However, the first error I received was `fatal error: 'RInside.h' file not found`.  I manually found this file and put it into the `/inst/examples/standard` directory and ran `make` again.  I received another fatal error for another .h file so I manually found the requisite file and inserted it into this standard directory.  Anyway, after doing that a few more times, all dependencies were taken care of, then I ran `make` again and received the following very strange error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I also tried using `clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++` in place of `g++` (since [RInside on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841842/rinside-on-mac-os-x) says that `g++` won't work), but it did not help either (i.e., I received the same architecture errors).

I am stuck here...

**UPDATE**:

As per Dirk Eddelbuettel's advice, I tried installing XTools (Run Windows X System on OSX), but I received the following error: "Xtools.pkg" is damaged and can't be opened.  You should eject the disk image."

I am concerned that running a simple "hello world" script as provided on the RInside webpage (http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) can be this convoluted on the Mac as to demand external installs and miscellaneous configurations.  Hence, there must be a more straightforward way to run RInside on the Mac OS X.

Comment: You need XTools.  And I think the command-line version.  Please see the `r-sig-mac` list for OS X issues, the `rcpp-devel` list for fallback as well as the Rcpp FAQ.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel XTools is from 2003 and all the sources providing its download provide "damaged" pkg files that can't be opened.  Could you please be more specific, and provide general advice for Mac OSX users, by answering my question in a complete answer.  It seems like I am not the only Mac user to have a problem with RInside, considering that XTools is advertised as "Run Windows X Sytems on OSX" which is not a very clean way of doing things.  I also followed your advice from old threads to install RInside from source.

Comment: Ask a well formed question with pertinent detail on the rcpp-devel list. *All our documentation* points there.  I do not own a Mac, so you are not likely to get an answer by yelling at me.

Comment: But to perfectly explicit:  http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_RInside.html shows the automated tests on CRAN still passing for both OS X variants.  This is not a source code issue but one with your setup.